# Why is vim reading system zipPlugin.vim after reading my .vimrc file?

Tags: vim

I have a line

```
set cpoptions+=$
```

in [my .vimrc](https://github.com/xiaotian/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc) file. However according to

```
verbose set cpoptions output:

cpoptions=aABceFs
Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
```

: it is always overridden by zipPlugin.vim. I am wondering why is vim reading these plugins **after** reading my `.vimrc` file? Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because vim always reads vimrc before the plugins. This load sequence makes sense because in this case you can set plugin options in the vimrc. It can’t be overriden, but you can source zipPlugin (with `:source /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/zipPlugin.vim` or `:runtime plugin/zipPlugin.vim`) from the vimrc. AFAIK it won’t prevent plugin from loading for the second time but as this plugin is using guard it won’t continue to the cpo resetting line when being sourced for the second time.

<s>Note that if your `zipPlugin.vim` is identical to mine, then it is not the source of the problem: if you look at its code you will see that it is saving your `cpoptions` setting and then restoring it. As other plugins distributed with vim must do the same or do not touch `cpoptions` at all then you can forget the above recommendation. I would suggest to first look that line `set nocompatible` (or `set nocp`), if any, is the first line present in the vimrc. Remember that setting this option causes many other options to reset to their defaults (including `cpoptions`) and it is why it *must* go before any other line modifying options.</s>

**Update:** Now I see that you have provided a link to the vimrc and it does not have the above problem. Try to check `verbose set compatible?`, then try to launch vim with the following command:

```
vim --cmd 'let g:sourced_files=[] | autocmd SourcePre * if !empty(g:sourced_files) && stridx(&cpo, "$")==-1 | echomsg "cpo does not contain dollar sign after loading ".g:sourced_files[-1] | set cpo+=$ | endif | let g:sourced_files+=[expand("<amatch>")]'
```

You will have some false positives here: first loaded vimrc (`/etc/vim/vimrc`): because `cpo` was not set, any plugins loaded like

```
if exists("loaded_thlnk")
    finish
endif
let loaded_thlnk = 1
let s:save_cpo = &cpo
set cpo&vim

" (This is to allow installation of thlnk.vim with just :runtime plugin/thlnk.vim
"  without leaving vim after having thrown all files into a plugin directory :)
runtime! plugin/thlnkuri.vim
runtime! plugin/thlnkarr.vim
runtime! plugin/thlnkscm.vim
```

: here cpo is reset before plugins are loaded, but at the end there goes

```
let &cpo = s:save_cpo
```

thus it is really safe. On my system there are only false positives: though cpo is saved and restored by many plugins, no plugins forget to restore it or do something else.

Comment: Now that @ZyX has explained the why, here's how you can make sure that  your ``cpoptions`` is set to what you want: put settings that you want to be protected against "corruption" by any plugin into any file in your ``~/.vim/after/plugin/``, for example ``~/.vim/after/plugin/myinvinciblesettings.vim``. Run ``vim`` again and then see the output of ``:scriptnames`` - it will show the list of scripts that vim sources in sequential order.